# Admin Grid in Catalog/category do a filter

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I want to have a filter to show push_ahead product in the respective category and a button to push_ahead and desactivate the push_ahead.
But it's just display all the product of the category...

Here is my code :

```
<?php

class MyCompany_Tetegondole_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tab_Pushahead extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product {

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load((int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0))->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('price');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('push_ahead', true);
    }

    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $this->addColumn('is_push', array(
            'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'name'      => 'is_push',
            'values'    => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'entity_id'
        ));
    }
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable'  => true,
        'width'     => '60',
        'index'     => 'entity_id'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
        'width'     => '80',
        'index'     => 'sku'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('price', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'width'     => '1',
        'currency_code' => (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE),
        'index'     => 'price'
    ));

    return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    // Set custom filter for in category flag
    if ($column->getId() == 'is_push') {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        Zend_Debug::dump($column);die;
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('push_ahead', array('in'=>$productIds));
        }
        elseif(!empty($productIds)) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('push_ahead', array('nin'=>$productIds));
        }
    }
    else {
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}

 protected function _getSelectedProducts()
{
    $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('is_push');
    if (is_null($productIds)) {
        $productIds = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
        return array_keys($productIds);
    }
    return $productIds;
}
```

}

```
<?php

class MyCompany_Tetegondole_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tab extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs{

/**
 * Prepare Layout Content
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->addTab('pushahead', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Produits Mis en avant'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('tetegondole/adminhtml_catalog_category_tab_pushahead', 'category.pushahead')->toHtml(),
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the line `$this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('push_ahead', true);` is called? I see that you apply the filter only if `$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()` returns true. Does that return true?

Comment: It was only that... Thank's.
Do you know can i add a button to push or dispush the product ?

Comment: I don't because I don't understand what `pusehd` is. But keep the questions separate. Add a new question explaining what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments....
the filter for `push_ahead` is applied only  when `$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()` returns `true`.
Removing the if statement resolves the problem.